# Putting PC3-8500 Memory in 2008 Macbook Pro

Tags: memory, macbook-pro

I've got some extra ram from my 2010 Macbook pro (PC3-8500). Is there any chance of this working with a Macbook 2008 motherboard (factory ram is is PC-5300).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No chance the 2008 Macbook uses DDR2 RAM and the 2010 DDR3 RAM; they are not compatible.  The PC3-8500 won't even physically install in the 2008 - the keying is different.